# Ligação iterativa de tabelas em R

Tags: r, join, redes

Estou a estudar um tema de redes e necessito representar todas as ligações entre um vertice e os que estão ligados a ele, direta e indiretamente, assim pensei em efetuar uma ligação iterativa entre tabelas do tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seja a tabela a ser usada no `left_join`:

```
ligacoes <- data.frame(origem=c("A","A", "B", "B", "D"), 
                       destino=c("B","D","C","D", "E"), 
                       valor=c(31.2, 100, 1, 85, 2))
```

Pretendia representar todas as ligações com origem no vértice A, para isso pensei efetuar um left join entre a tabela ligacoes e a tabela ligacoes ligando a coluna destino da primeira com a coluna origem da segunda, tantas vezes quantas as vezes em que a correspondência devolver resultados (neste exemplo amostra teria apenas 2 left join uma vez que o 3º left_join já não devolve resultados contudo no dataset podem existir casos em que seja necessário um maior numero de left_join).  Alguem poderia me ajudar? Obg

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira mais simples de fazer o que precisa é representar seus dados como grafo. O pacote igraph é ótimo para isso. Expandi seu exemplo para incluir ligações que não partem de A:

```
library(igraph)

ligacoes <- data.frame(
  origem  = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "D", "F", "G", "F"),
  destino = c("B", "D", "C", "D", "E", "G", "H", "H"),
  valor = c(31.2, 100, 1, 85, 2, 4, 7, 8))

# Converte os dados de origem e destino em objeto igraph
grafo <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(ligacoes[1:2]))

# Inclui a variável valor como atributo das conexões:
E(grafo)$valor <- ligacoes$valor

plot(grafo)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As funções `*ego` são usadas para identificar a vizinhança de um nó. A `make_ego_graph` retorna as vizinhanças como uma lista de objetos igraph (pois pode haver mais de uma), preservando os atributos. Se usar a opção `order` (número máximo de conexões até os nós indicados) com um valor bastante alto, terá todas as conexões com A. A opção `mode = "out"` indica para seguir as conexões que saem.

```
grafoA <- make_ego_graph(grafo, order = 1e9, nodes = "A", mode = "out")[[1]]

plot(grafoA, edge.label = E(grafoA)$valor)

plot(grafoA)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito interessante a solução. No meu caso tenho milhares de ligações diretas entre vértices e necessito de listar numa tabela o vértice origem (p.e. A) com todos os vértices aos quais este esteja ligado direta e indiretamente, no exemplo que indica seria: A-B, A-D, A-C (através de B), A-E (através de D)). Registar o nº de conexões também seria interessante bem como os pesos (p.e. A-E apresenta 2 arestas e o peso final seria 100*2). Penso que a solução indicada não permite a construção da tabela necessária.

Comment: Tudo isso pode ser feito pelo *igraph*, mas o que está pedindo é muito amplo para este espaço. Primeiro veja a documentação e tutoriais do pacote e, se necessário, poste perguntas sobre dificuldades pontuais e específicas que encontrar. Lembre-se que [o SO não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas).